# Angular get url parameters in router-outlet

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 7 app with several outlet routes. My routes variable is as follows.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "spa/:id",
    component: TopforecastComponent,
    outlet: 'topforecast',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: FrettirComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: SidebarComponent,
    outlet: 'sidebar'
  },
  {
    path: 'spa/:id',
    component: FrettirComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'spa/:id',
    component: SidebarComponent,
    outlet: 'sidebar'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: TopforecastComponent,
    outlet: 'topforecast'
  },
  {
    path: "spa/:id/:ar/:man/:dagur",
    component: DagsspaComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'frett/:id',
    component: FrettComponent
  }
];
```

When I try to retrieve the parameters in the topforecast component (topforecast outlet) I get undefined.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params)
    });
  }
```

Here is the component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-topforecast',
  templateUrl: './topforecast.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./topforecast.component.css']
})
export class TopforecastComponent implements OnInit {
  users$: Object;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

How can I access the url parameter from outlet path.

Comment: Is this.route a Component of type ActivatedRoute?

Comment: You have two routes with same component TopforecastComponent. Since you have the path as ' ', it is showing undefined

Comment: What are you injecting in your constructor for 'route'?

Comment: I want it to be undefined when the path is '', however when the path is /spa/7, I want to be able to obtain the 7.

I will edit the question to show the component, what I include and so on. The constructor uses ActivatedRoute.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```html
<router-outlet
  #r="outlet"
  (activate)="checkRoute(r.activatedRoute, r. activatedRouteData)"
  (attached)="checkRoute(r.activatedRoute, r. activatedRouteData)"
></router-outlet>
```